# Own extension javascript on chrome doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I looked on this site and several others (but on this site you get more specific answers so that's good.) but I can't seem to find the correct answer. A lot of people asked similar questions but my problem still seems to persist.

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension that gets the text from some titles throught a shortcut. I'm fairly new to scripting so my way of working is do everything step by step. I fail at the first step already.

I'll just head to it. This is in my **manifest.json:**

```
  {
        "name": "grab some",
        "description": "grab some texts from html titles",
         "version": "1.0",
            "manifest_version": 2,

       "content_scripts": [ {
          "js": [ "content_scripts.js" ],
          "matches": [ "*://something.com/*"]
       } ]

     }
```

This is in my **content_scripts.js:**

```
document.onkeyup=function(y){
  if(y.ctrlKey && y.which == 89) {
    alert('Keyboard shortcut working!');
    return false;
  }
};

document.addEventListener('keyup', doc_keyUp, false);
```

I keep getting nothing. If I put the exact code of the content_scripts.js in a javascript applier (cjs-extension). Then it works perfectly. My question is just: Why does it not work when I try to do this in my own extension?

Btw; there will be some errors in the way I asked my question, sorry for that. But I hope you understand what I am trying to ask.

Comment: First thing I see is that `"matches": "*://something./*"` isn't a valid [match pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns). You probably want something like `"matches": "*://something.com/*"`. You should **not** use both `document.onkeyup` and `document.addEventListener('keyup',…)`. In general, you should not add event listeners using the `on*` properties. You should be in the habit of using `addEventListener()` to add event handlers. don't use `y` as the variable name for the event. Use `event` (or `e`). Don't mix variable naming schemes `doc_keyUp` should be `docKeyUp`.

Comment: If I follow what you say, it doesn't do anything anymore, not even in the cjs extension.

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]. You use the `doc_keyUp` function, but have not shown how it is defined.

Comment: Why are you creating a keyboard shortcut listener yourself instead of using a [`commands`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) entry in your *manifest.json*. `commands` and `chrome.commands` entire purpose is to create keyboard shortcut keys for your extension.

Comment: FYI: To reliably detect a multi-key combination which includes Ctrl, Alt, etc. you need to detect the `keydown` event.The reason for this is that, in your case, the user doing: Ctrl-key down, y-key down, Ctrl-key up, y-key up is a valid keyboard shortcut, but is not detected if you are listening for the `keyup` event which matches the y-key, but must also have the `ctrlKey` property true. You can choose to activate on either the detected `keydown`, or wait for the `keyup` of the primary key.

Comment: You can play around with: `function reportKey(e){console.log('e.key: ', e.key, ':: e.ctrlKey:', e.ctrlKey, ':: e:' ,e);} document.addEventListener('keyup',reportKey); document.addEventListener('keydown',reportKey);` to see the events which are fired with different user actions. Make a choice as to what user actions you desire to detect (or just use a *manifest.json* `commands` entry). Note: I show [`event.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) here because [`event.which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Your extension functions fine for me. I just put it into two files (manifest.json and content_scripts.js) and loaded it via Chrome -> Extensions -> Load unpacked extension (after activating developer mode). However, I changed "something" into a page I actually have access to (`"matches": [ "*://stackoverflow.com/*"]`).

This leaves me with the following:

- You're also German, using an english keyboard layout with a German keyboard and pressed ctrl+y, which turns out to be ctrl+z (not kidding, this was *my* first mistake)
- Your `matches` pattern does not actually match. Click on "Details" on the extension page, for me it says *"Permissions: Read and change your data on stackoverflow.com"*.

  - On a side node, because it was mentioned in comments: When your pattern actually was completely crap, Chrome would tell you on the extensions page. This, obviously, does not mean it does match when it is not.
- Note that you can't simply enter anything within "matches" and use the extension on any other page. This won't work.
- Some other event is catching yours, that is, an `addEventListener` with `useCapture` set to true (see [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener))
- You already fixed the bug and forgot to click "Reload" on the extensions page (happens a lot of times to me when I write extensions)
- You have to refresh the page before the extension can insert the content script.

Oh, and what already was mentioned: Your second `addEventListener` is throwing errors since the function does not exist.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: doc_keyUp is not defined
>       at content_scripts.js:8

However, in my test, this was not a problem.